# HTML fields occupy the entire width of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a form in HTML 5 as I mentioned before, but when I create the form the fields are too large, that is, they occupy the entire width of the page, as I show in the following image,

[image]

this is my code in HTML5,

```
<div id="divCreateGenders" data-bind="visible: IsNew">
    <form id="FormCreateGenders" method="post">
        <div class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: GenderModel">
            <h3><strong>Crear Nuevo</strong></h3>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Codigo:</strong></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="TextboxGenderId" name="TextboxGenderId" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: GenderId" maxlength="1" placeholder="Por ejemplo, I" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Genero:</strong></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="TextboxGenderName" name="TextboxGenderName" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: GenderName" maxlength="15" placeholder="Introduzca un genero..." required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $parent.Create">Crear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

could someone help me with this, since I have little knowledge of css, I would appreciate the help

Comment: bootstrap inputs are always 100% of their container's width.  Why not change your col-md-10 to col-md-5 or something like that if you want the input smaller

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reduce the `col-width` of the `bootstrap column` containing the textbox (form-field)

```
<label class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Genero:</strong></label>
<div class="col-md-10"> --Reduce this to a smaller column width
     <input id="TextboxGenderName" name="TextboxGenderName" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: GenderName" maxlength="15" placeholder="Introduzca un genero..." required />
</div>
```

Instead of using a column width of 10 reduce it to 2 or 3 or 4 etc. until it is the width you want. Also, if you want to keep this responsive for different view sizes you'll want to use `col-lg` `col-md` `col-sm` and `col-xs` with appropriate column width value to keep it at the correct size for when the screen width is either modified or viewed on different devices.

Like so:

```
<label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>Genero:</strong></label>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"> --Just an example
    <input id="TextboxGenderName" name="TextboxGenderName" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: GenderName" maxlength="15" placeholder="Introduzca un genero..." required />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

should do the trick.

Alternatively you could use `%` or `vw` instead of `px` depending on your use case.

or you could change your `col-md-10` to something smaller like `col-md-4`